# Fancy way to implement an average function in BASH?

Tags: bash, function, shell

I'm really really new in shell script programming.

I would like to implement an averaging function in bash and have searched, but have not got any exact ways to make it.

What I would like to do is:

***method_1***:

```
function avg(item_1, item_2, item_3){
    if(item_2 == null and item_3){
        return item_1
    }else if(item_3 == null){
        return (item_1 + item_2) / 2
    }else{
        return (item_1 +item_2 + item_3)/3
    }
}
```

or if possible:

***method_2***:

```
function avg(item[]){
    return sum(item)/item.length
}
```

Does anyone have a fancy way to make it?

Thank you for your helping!!!

Comment: Have you attempted anything for this yet? You are generally expected to make some effort to solve our problem before asking about it on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Bash only knows integer arithmetics, so it's better to use external tool to do the maths. Here, I used `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

avg () {
    local IFS=+
    echo $(bc -l <<< "($*) / $#")
}

avg 2 2.25 3.1
```

`$*` in double quotes connects the positional parameters with the first character of `$IFS`.

Comment: Just use `local IFS=+` so you don't have to worry about correctly restoring `IFS` (your code sets `IFS` even if it was unset before `avg` was called. For POSIX, you can sometimes work around the lack of `local` by using a subshell as the body of the function (`avg () ( IFS=+; ... )`)

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, updated. I didn't know IFS could be localized. I know the subshell trick, but it's usually quite slow.